# Using ZendStudio with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, zend-studio

I had installed XAMPP, as a matter of convenience, since it installs php, apache (which is what I need) and, in addition, it installs other things like MySQL, but I'm not going to use now.

In XAMPP, I enabled the mssql module (editing the php.ini), to use the connection to Microsoft SQL, and everything works fine.

Now, I'm wanting to debug a script in PHP debugger with ZendStudio and I notice that there are two ways:

- Internal
- Server
- [Internal], uses the ZendStudio "internal" PHP.
- [Server], connect to a server (which is what I need).

The point is that I can not do it, I can not understand how it is configured. 
I would like to use with the XAMPP apache and php.

I use Internal for now, but I get problems with the mssql module. I was looking at the Zend internal php, copied by hand the mssql dll and edited the php.ini (I am talking about the Zend) but still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install either Zend Debugger or xdebug on the server, and then configure Zend Studio accordingly. Both are fairly easy to install on XAMPP, and there are many articles available through Google that detail installation better than I can here.

If you choose to go with Zend Debugger, you shouldn't need to do anything else in Zend Studio, as it is the default debugger. If you opt for xdebug, you will need to edit your Studio configuration to use xdebug instead. This option can be found under *PHP > Debug*, and is a drop-down labeled *PHP Debugger*.

Now you can start a debugging or profiling session using the Zend Studio browser toolbar, or from the Remote Debug or Remote Profiling buttons in Studio. I highly suggest reading the Zend Studio manual for some more advanced debugging information.

Also, just to throw this out there, you can replace XAMPP with Zend Server Community, which has Zend Debugger installed and configured by default. Studio 7+ will pick up a Server installation and configures itself to use it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that familiar with ZendStudio, but wouldn't you just use the "Server" option and point to http://localhost/ for the server to connect to?

Comment: Yep, that is what I thought. But, it does not work. And, It does not give many information. 
By the way, what do you use for php debugging??